# Can the non striking batsman be out if he blocks the field, having been injured

Tags: cricket

Situation in a match was, the striking batsman hit the ball. It immediately hit the non striker, whilst the non striker was a few yards outside his crease. The ball fell to the floor, the non striker doubled up in pain, and the bowler picked up the ball and ran out the non-striker.

1. Was the ball dead after it hit the non-striker?
2. If not, would the ball have been dead if the non-striker had fallen to the ground, or was otherwise clearly unable to continue?
3. Had he fallen to the ground on top of the ball and blocked the fielder, could he have been out obstructing the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, the ball is not dead if it hits the non-striker. For perhaps the most famous incident of this, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFZM0OkJxG4) where Andrew Symonds was caught off his teammate Michael Clarke's heel.
2. Yes. [Law 23.4(b)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/) states:

> Either umpire shall call and signal Dead ball when [...] (ii) a serious injury to a player or umpire occurs.

3. No, even if the ball were not dead. [Law 37](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-37-obstructing-the-field/) states

> Either batsman is out Obstructing the field if he **wilfully** attempts to obstruct or distract the fielding side by word or action.

(my emphasis). An injured player is clearly not wilfully attempting very much at all.

While the above is what the Laws state, I'll say it is *clearly* against the spirit of the Laws to run out a player injured in this manner. I'd strongly hope that the captain of the fielding time would withdraw any appeal made.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was clearly against the spirit of the game, but unfortunately the opposing captain and coach didn't see it that way.